# Magento CSS not loading

Tags: css

My second question. i am trying to help make small changes to my Dad's website. I have made changes to his css which work fine when i inspect element and copy modified css into it. Then i logged into his server where the file is and got to the correct path which is http://www.brooklynbigandtall.co.uk/skin/frontend/default/magezon/css/styles.css. Then i cleared the cache at both ends, cleared out css/javascript cache but it still isnt taking effect. When i look into the server and get the css file called styles.css it shows my changes in there BUT when i view page source and look at the css thats loaded from the same path, my changes are not in it.

His web address is www.brooklynbigandtall.co.uk
Really puzzled. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Template used is magezon and we are running magento 1.9.1.0

Comment: may be you files are load from server cache.

Comment: but i flushed the cache from cms back end. If i can do it manually from somewhere else please let me know. I have some idea that Its in var folder in root but what do i do from there

Comment: i'm not sure about this, may be the files are cached in server side (not in magento).
[Link](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8057/clearing-the-server-cache-using-website-accelerator)

Comment: can you explain, what are the changes you have made in css file?

Comment: #nav a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
#nav li>a>span{color:white;}
#nav a>span:hover { display:block; line-height:1em; text-decoration:none;font-size:22px;color:#B41420;}

Comment: #nav li:hover>a>span{color:#b41420;}

Comment: did you click on clear css/javascript cache

Comment: I certainly did:)

Answer (score 1):

Magento use Sass and override all your changes in the style.css. You must edit the right sass file with any Editor and then compare it with compass or other.

Comment: I am pretty sure we are not using sass. Also sass isnt compatible with magento 1.9. its compatibility stops at 1.8.1

Comment: Also if we were using sass with 1.9 that would imply that our site would be using rwd???? its not responsive at all :) so unless somebody sheds more light on this I am ruling out sass

Comment: also wouldnt the url for css when i look at page source reflect that?

Comment: @waqar_lionheart sass is compatible with mage 1.9 why wouldn't it be?